# Durandal, Knockout binding class to view - no output

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, knockout.js, durandal

Viewmodel

```
define([
'services/blogrepository',
'plugins/router'], function (blogrepository, router) {

 var Blog = function(data) {
    this.ID = ko.observable(data.BID);
    this.Titel = ko.observable(data.BTitel);
    this.Content = ko.observable(data.BContent);
    this.Time = ko.observable(data.BTimestamp);
    }

var viewmodel = function () {
    this.router = router;
    this.blogrepository = blogrepository;
    this.blogentries = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.blogrepository.getAllBlog()
                    .then(function (result) {

                         this.blogentries = $.map(result, function (item) { return new Blog(item) });

                    });


    this.activate = function () {
    };

    this.attached = function (view, parent) {

    };

};

return viewmodel;});
```

View

```
<article data-bind="foreach: blogentries">
    <span data-bind="text: Titel"> </span>
</article>
```

Hello everybody,

i cant display the blogentries in the View. What i do not see here?

getAllBlog() is doing good, i get the Data and if i console.log the blogentries he is telling me this:

```
[Blog, Blog]
0: Blog
Content: c()
ID: c()
Time: c()
Titel: c()
__proto__: Blog
1: Blog
Content: c()
ID: c()
Time: c()
Titel: c()
__proto__: Blog
```

Thanks alot and have a nice sunday.

Chris

Comment: Try adding the Durandal plugin "Observable". This makes the ViewModel a lot easier to manage as there is no (well hidden) Knockout. However you must run on an ES6 get/set compatible browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.blogentries = $.map(...);
```

You're assigning to blogentries rather than setting its contents. That throws away its `observableArray`. Instead,

```
this.blogentries($.map(...));
```

**Update**: You also have a `this` problem. Within a function, the value of `this` changes from what it was outside the function. It is a good practice at to have the line

```
var self = this;
```

as the first line of any constructor. Within the constructor, use `self` instead of `this` so you always know what you are referencing. It is a very common gotcha. You should also consider whether you really need a constructor, or just a function that returns an object.

Comment: He throws now this error: 
    Uncaught TypeError: this.blogentries is not a function

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ChristopherTardel Updated.